# Converting ORC to JSON in Java

Tags: java, hive, orc

I'm trying to convert the output ORC file into JSON in Java within the unit tests. I've been reading their unit tests and inspired by:

```
     PrintStream origOut = System.out;
      String outputFilename = "orc-file-dump.json";
      String tmpFileLocationJson = createTempFileJson();
      FileOutputStream myOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpFileLocationJson);

      // replace stdout and run command
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(myOut, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
      FileDump.main(new String[]{"data", tmpFileLocationJson});
      System.out.flush();
      System.setOut(origOut);
      System.out.println("done");
```

Something like this. The problem is I'm not quite sure how to equate this code to the java utils utilization:

`java -jar orc-tools-1.5.5-uber.jar data output-1595448128191.orc` for example, outputs the following JSON dump.

```
{"integerExample":1,"nestedExample":{"sub1":"value1","sub2":42},"dateExample":"2018-01-04"}
```

So I want to convert the ORC into JSON so I can cross-reference in my unit tests.

Edit: This may be package private :(
https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/b9e82b3d7b473201bdcf46011c3b2fda10ef897f/java/tools/src/java/org/apache/orc/tools/PrintData.java#L227

Comment: I have never used orc-tools and I'm sure you can do it this way. What I did in the past though is use this library: https://github.com/eclecticlogic/eclectic-orc
It works with Hibernate and provides an easy way to read orc files... Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks Chaud. I just wrote my own impl using inspiration from Hive. Maybe your approach is better, trying to keep this pretty lightweight, but Ill check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I vendored the code from Hive and overwrote outputstream to filewriter and redirected output into file to read back into the test.

```
  static void printJsonData(String fileName, PrintStream printStream,
      Reader reader) throws IOException, JSONException, org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException {
//    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(printStream, "UTF-8");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName.concat(".json")));
    RecordReader rows = reader.rows();
    try {
      TypeDescription schema = reader.getSchema();
      VectorizedRowBatch batch = schema.createRowBatch();
      while (rows.nextBatch(batch)) {
        for (int r = 0; r < batch.size; ++r) {
          JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(out);
          printRow(writer, batch, schema, r);
          out.write("\n");
          out.flush();
          if (printStream.checkError()) {
            throw new IOException("Error encountered when writing to stdout.");
          }
        }
      }
    } finally {
      rows.close();
    }
  }
```